# Enable CORS Post Request from AngularJS to Jersey

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, jersey, cors

I'm attempting to post a JSON document from an AngularJS app to a Jersey REST service. The request fails, informing me that:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/my.rest.service/api/order/addOrder. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.`

### Jersey REST Post Function

I have enabled (what I believe to be) the appropriate headers: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` on the response, as seen in the method below:

```
@POST
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/addOrder")
public Response addOrder(DBObject dbobject) {
    DB db = mongo.getDB("staffing");
    DBCollection col = db.getCollection("orders");
    col.insert(dbobject);
    ObjectId id = (ObjectId)dbobject.get("_id");
    return Response.ok()
            .entity(id)
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
            .allow("OPTIONS")
            .build();
}
```

### Angular JS Controller

I've declared the app and configured the $httpProvider with all of the settings suggested in similar Stack Overflow questions:

```
var staffingApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap']);
myApp.config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json";
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
 }]);
```

I've also created this controller to open a modal and handle the form:

```
    var modalCtrl = function($scope, $modal, $log, $http, $location) {          
    $scope.order = {
        activityTitle : null,
        anticipatedAwardDate : null,
        component : null,
        activityGroup : null,
        activityCategory : null,
        activityDescription : null
    };
    $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'addOrder.html',
            windowClass: 'modal',
            controller: modalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {
                order : function () {
                    return $scope.order;
                    }
                }
            });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (oid) {
            $log.info("Form Submitted, headed to page...");
            $location.path("/orders/" + oid);
        }, function() { 
            $log.info("Form Cancelled")
        });
    };
};

var modalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, $log, $http, order) {
    $scope.order = order,
    $scope.ok = function () {
        $log.log('Submitting user info');
        $log.log(order);
        $log.log('And now in JSON....');
        $log.log(JSON.stringify(order));
        $http.post('http://localhost:8080/my.rest.service/api/order/addOrder', JSON.stringify(order)).success(function(data){
            $log.log("here's the data:\n");
            $log.log(data);
            $modalInstance.close(data._id.$oid)
        });
    };
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };      
};
myApp.controller('modalCtrl', modalCtrl);
```

To no avail, I've tried:

- removing `.allow("OPTIONS")` from the response headers.
- removing the $httpProvider configuration from the application
- changed the $httpProvider configuration to call myApp.config(function ($httpProvider) {...}), passing the function itself rather than the array.

Get requests work with the same configuration:

```
@GET
@Path("/listall/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listAll(){
    DB db = mongo.getDB("staffing");
    DBCollection col = db.getCollection("orders");
    List<DBObject> res = col.find().limit(200).toArray();
    return Response.ok()
            .entity(res.toString())
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*")
            .header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT")
            .allow("OPTIONS")
            .build();       
}
```

with this controller that works fine:

```
myApp.controller('orderListCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/my.rest.service/api/order/listall').success(function(data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].description.length > 200) {
                data[i].shortDesc = data[i].description.substring(0,196) + "...";
            } else {
                data[i].shortDesc = data[i].description;
            }
        };
        $scope.orders = data;
    });
});
```

### Update #1:

I've tried the same request on a same origin basis, essentially serving the Angular application alongside the REST service from locahost:8080. This configuration worked, but required a slight change and some general clean up in my code, which I've edited above.

The Post still fails as a CORS request, however so I'm still looking for the missing piece in this configuration.

### Update #2:

I've investigated the headers of the working request as they're delivered to the browser and compared them with the non-working request.

The working get request returns the following headers with its response:
[image: Working GET Request Response]

The non-working post request returns headers with its response, but is missing the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header:

[image: Non-working POST Request Response]

I believe this has now become an issue of the headers being stripped off of the response prior to returning it to the client, which would then cause the browser to fail the request.

### Update #3:

Submitting a test POST request to the same URL from Chrome's REST Console extension returns the appropriate response headers, as seen in the screencap below.
[image: REST Console Screencap]

At this point, I can't determine what's removing the headers between Jersey and my Angular client, but I'm fairly confident that's the culprit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem turned out to be inadequate handling of the OPTIONS request sent in pre-flight prior to the POST request with the proper cross origin headers.

I was able to resolve the issue by downloading and implementing the CORS filter found at this page: http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html.

If you're experiencing a similar problem, follow the instructions and test to see that your OPTIONS request is no longer failing, and is immediately followed by your successful request.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to add Jersey Response filter which will add the CORS headers for all the methods. You don't have to change your webservices implementation.

I will explain for Jersey 2.x

1) First add a ResponseFilter as shown below

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerResponseFilter;

public class CorsResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext,   ContainerResponseContext responseContext)
    throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");

  }
}
```

2) then in the web.xml , in the jersey servlet declaration add the below

```
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>YOUR PACKAGE.CorsResponseFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar CORS error while calling my Restful service (implemented in java - Jersey) from angularjs. To fix it I added **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** in response header. I added below :

```
response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

For more information you can check - http://enable-cors.org/server.html

CORS error occurs typically when your angularjs code (web project) and webserivce code (server side project) are on different IP and port no.

Your webservice implementation looks correct. So just to check, try running them on localhost on same port (eg. 8080). It should work there if all code is correct.

In order to run them separately try adding **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *** in webservice implementation as shown above.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What are you suggesting the response object is in your code above? And is this functionally different from including the same response header in the response builder?

Comment: It worked for me when I added only "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" in the rest webservice response. I can see you already have set it in response. Please try to run your code on same IP and Port No so you know for sure there is no issue in angular code.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you have other solution that does not need a filter. Adding the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers to the `GET` request, is not enough, you have to create an `OPTIONS` endpoint to allow browsers do the pre-flight request, i.e.:

```
@OPTIONS
public Response corsMyResource(@HeaderParam("Access-Control-Request-Headers") String requestH) {
    ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok();

    return buildResponse(rb, requestH);
}
```

see https://kdecherf.com/blog/2011/06/19/java-jersey-a-cors-compliant-rest-api/ for reference.