# AJAX POST To Jersey enabled RESTful Webservice Cross Domain

Tags: ajax, cordova, rest, jersey, cors

I am developing a Cordova/PhoneGap application communicating existing Restful web-services (Jersey). The web services are just fine because I already developed the Android version of my app and it is working OK. Now I am developing Cordova based for iOS. I've read stuff about CORS and related stuff about cross domain AJAX call. But sending the AJAX request results in following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://xxxx:xxxx/api/v1/general/authenticate1. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Also in the server side log every AJAX call creates a bunch of logs with this message:

> INFO: Couldn't find grammar element for class
>   com.test.database.PeopleAuth Jun 08, 2015 5:49:07 PM
>   com.sun.jersey.server.wadl.generators.AbstractWadlGeneratorGrammarGenerator
>   attachTypes

Please check following codes and tell me whats wrong here.

This is my AJAX code at client side:

```js
var j = {IMEI: ximei, IMSI: ximsi}; 
var d = JSON.stringify(j);
console.log(d);
$.ajax({
    url:baseurl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:'json',     
    type:'POST',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: d,
    success:function(callbak) {
        console.log(callbak);
    },
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
        //console.log(textStatus);
        //console.log(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

and this is my Webservice's Filter added for CORS headers stuff

```java
@Provider
public class CORSResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter  {

    @Override
    public ContainerResponse filter(ContainerRequest requestContext, ContainerResponse responseContext) {

        responseContext.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        //responseContext.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD");
        responseContext.getHttpHeaders().putSingle("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With");

        return responseContext;
    }

}
```

also the web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TEST REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.pckg</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.test.webservices.CORSResponseFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

**Update #1:**
I've tested the web services with Rest Console (Google Chrome Extention) and they are working OK.

Comment: Your have the wrong `<init-param>` for your package scanning. This `jersey.config.server.provider.packages` should be `com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages`

Comment: @peeskillet thanks for your reply, but i don't think that's the case because as i said the webservices are working fine with requests from android

Comment: If your app is working with the init-param (which is wrong), it's possible your entire web.xml is useless. Try adding `@Provider` to the CORS filter. Also are there any exceptions in the log or is it all info logs?

Comment: @peeskillet , i will test what you said, the logs are all INFO log

Comment: I've added @Provider to CORSFilter, but nothing happened and same result

Comment: If  you say that your resources are working, then add a `@OPTIONS` resource method, and add the headers there. This is not a solution, just seeing if it _is_ just the filter not registering or its some other problem

Comment: @peeskillet I saw this in catalina.out Jun 09, 2015 11:57:40 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider
class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonMappingExceptionMapper
class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider
class com.test.webservices.CORSResponseFilter
class org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JsonParseExceptionMapper

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a library for CORPS. 
read more at [dzhuvinov](http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html), same problem like mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860490/enable-cors-post-request-from-angularjs-to-jersey) .

Problem solved but I don't know why,and really want to find out (looking for it), if any one knows please comment.

Answer (score -1):

For cross domain you need to use JSONP instead of JSON as type. Ensure this supported as serverside code as well.

Change

```
dataType:'json',
```

to

```
dataType: 'jsonp'
```

Refer here for difference
[Difference between dataType jsonp and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10852652/difference-between-datatype-jsonp-and-json)