# JAX-RS Access-Control-Allow-Origin header not present, but it was added in ResponseFilter

Tags: java, rest, angular, jersey, jax-rs

I'm trying to connect to my REST endpoint built using JAX-RS, but I get the response that the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is not present. Trying to GET a resource with Angular2.

**What I've tried**

I tried the solution presented in https://stackoverflow.com/a/30450944.

My response filter:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        responseContext.getHeaders().add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD");
    }
}
```

And my web.xml servlet mapping:

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
            <param-value>com.api.ResponseFilter</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

**Update 1**

Updated the

```
responseContext.getHeaders().add(...);
```

to

```
responseContext.getHeaders.putSingle(...);
```

but I'm still getting the same error.
While testing in postman, I am getting the correct headers back:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers →origin, content-type, accept, authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
```

**Update 2**

In my JAXRSConfig, which extends Application, I've manually added all resources possibly necessary:

```
@ApplicationPath("api")
public class JAXRSConfig extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<>();
        addRestResourceClasses(resources);
        return resources;
    }

    private void addRestResourceClasses(Set<Class<?>> resources) {
        resources.add(AdminResource.class);
        resources.add(RequestFilter.class);
        resources.add(ResponseFilter.class);
        resources.add(TweetResource.class);
        resources.add(UserResource.class);
    }
}
```

Via the use of breakpoints I have noticed that my ResponseFilter does get invoked when I send a GET request via Postman, but it does not get invoked when I send a GET request via my angular application.

My angular code to send a request:

```
let headers = new Headers({'Authorization': authToken});
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(http://localhost:8080/api/object/user)
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

**Update 3**

I did realize I did not actually add the defined headers to the request; so I've updated my angular code to:

```
let authToken = "Basic " + btoa("henk:asdf");//temporary until I learn how to allow a user to log in, in angular
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    headers.append('Authorization', authToken);

    //let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers});

    return this.http.get(this.myUrl, {headers: headers})
      .map((res:Response) => res.json())
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

**Update 4**

I've since learned this could be due to the pre-flight check Chrome (and other browsers) perform, via a request-method called OPTIONS. I've added a request filter to my api as follows:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class RequestFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        if (requestContext.getRequest().getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
            requestContext.abortWith(Response.status(Response.Status.OK).header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200").build());
        }
    }
}
```

But to no avail. With a break point on the if-statement I've seen that this method does not get called in a GET request from angular, but it does get called from a request from Postman.

I've also tried a different CORS filter according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902666/6795661.
But this did not work either.

**Update 5**

As per [peeskillet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2587435/peeskillet) I've tried creating a class that implements javax.servlet.Filter, to add the required header(s) to a response:

```
public class ContainerResponseFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:4200");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        res.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

With the corresponding mapping in my web.xml:

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>corsfilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.api.ContainerResponseFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>corsfilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

And I've added ContainerResponseFilter as resource in my Application configuration.
Unfortunately I am still getting the error that the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is not present.

Comment: I see you're using basic auth in your angular request. What type of security (architecture) are you using? If you are using some servlet level filter (like with Sprig Security), your Jersey filter will not be called because servlet level filters will always be called before reaching Jersey. It you have this kind of security architecture, then configure the CORS at _that_ level, not at the Jersey level

Comment: The reason it would work with Postman, is that Postman doesn't require any CORS support to work

Comment: I am using JAAS with a basic authentication setup, this checks a username and password combination in a jdbc realm. I have this configured in my application server (Payara). For basic authentication a GET request needs an authorization header and a base64 encoded string of a username and password, which is what you see below update 3. As you can see at the bottom of update 4, I've tried implementing a CORS filter with a servlet mapping in my web.xml, but this did not work either.

Comment: I don't know anything about Payara, but you probably need to configure the CORS at the container level. Search for anything regarding configuring  CORS specifically with Payara

Comment: _I've tried implementing a CORS filter with a servlet mapping in my web.xml, but this did not work either._ - this is useless (and not even configured correctly even if it wasn't useless. Your registration in the `Application` class is correct. But like I said, this is not the problem).

Comment: You can also try to use a servlet `Filter` and add the CORS headers _there_. Maybe that will work. But like I said, I know nothing of Payara

Comment: Have I not configured it at the container level with my request & response filters? These implement ContainerResponseFilter and ContainerRequestFilter. When I look up implementations of a CORS filter in glassfish (payara is a continuation of glassfish) I can only find examples such as I have already tried with the filters previously mentioned.

Comment: No. I said it's not configured correctly, because 1) JSF does not have any such init-param (this is specific to Jersey) and 2) It is a component specific to JAX-RS. Try to use a sevlet `Filter` like I mentioned, and add that as a `<filter>` to the `web.xml`

Comment: For example [filter](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/java/java-jersey2/src/main/java/io/swagger/sample/util/ApiOriginFilter.java) and [config](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/blob/master/java/java-jersey2/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml#L46)

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks for the links to the examples! I believe I've done it exactly as I should have, including the mapping in web.xml and adding the new Filter as a resource in my Application; though I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Do this. Remove any authentication for the server. If the request works then I think this is the problem: the request flow goes Auth -> Filter -> Jersey. The Auth is something that is performed on the server even before any filter is reached. And this is a problem, because instead of getting the CORS headers, you just get an unauthenticated message. If this is the case, then I am not sure how you can implement this. This is something that need to be configured at even an earlier stage of the request, which will be specific to your server

Comment: Another thing I noticed is that you took out `authorization` from the allowed headers in your new filter.

Comment: Thank you so much for your extended help @peeskillet ! It turns out it is indeed the authentication that's the problem, after removing that my request goes through fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was with the authentication. My application server was trying to authenticate the request, but since a CORS check is done before the authentication I just got an unauthorized response, which did not include the required header.