# Unable to extract response body in Angular.js

Tags: java, angularjs, netbeans

I have a GET method hello world service that quite simply returns "Hello world" to anyone who accesses it.
If I access this method through a REST API tool, everything works just fine and the response is returned.
Even stranger is that by examining the logs I know that the request is being submitted just fine, however I cannot return the extract the body from the response.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Mainstyle.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>        
</head>

<div ng-app="betaApp" ng-controller="betaController">
    <p>The url of this page is:</p>
    <h3>{{"Server says: " + mywelcome}}</h3>
    <p>{{temp}}</p>

    <title>Beta</title>
    <div id="betaform" class="display">
        <p>{{5+5}}</p>          
    </div>
</div>


<script>
    var app = angular.module('betaApp', []);
    app.controller('betaController', function($scope, $http, $location) {
        $scope.temp = $location.absUrl();
        $http({
             url: "http://localhost:8080/API/HelloWorld", 
             method: "GET",
             params: {}  
        }).then(function (response) {
            $scope.mywelcome = response.data;
            $scope.testobj = response.status;
        });

    });
</script>
```

The result of this code will have the variable temp displayed properly, but not myWelcome or testobj.
I believe this implies the issue is with this segment of code:

```
.then(function (response) {
            $scope.mywelcome = response.data;
            $scope.testobj = response.status;
        })
```

But due to my unfamiliarity with angular.js, I am unsure as to what exactly is going wrong or why.
My call matches the documentation, yet it is not working, which is most peculiar.

---

**UPDATE:** I have found a very basic solution, however I will not propose it as the answer since I do not like it and feel like there is a better way.
The issue is that the response is being blocked due to [CORS](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) related reasons.
This has been "solved" by altering the response on the server side in each method.

```
Response.status(200).entity("Hello World.").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
```

However, the astute among you would identify that this means one would need to add the header to every method, which seems arduous. I shall look in to the possibility of there being a better way.

**UPDATE 2:** Far nicer and simpler solution has been found, but as this has been flagged as duplicate I can't do much other than link to what I feel is the [right solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40712039/4817002)
Updated tags since this is a question that is technically about server issues.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in the line `$scope.mywelcome = response.data` and inspected the contents of `response`?

Comment: Start with `.then(function (response) { console.log(response); ...`  and look in your console to see what you get. (Your data is probably not a json-response?) Also, if you suspect an error, implement the $http error handler: `$http().then(successHandler, errorHandler);`

Comment: Having examined the console the issue is due to a lack of an "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header. Will update with more info on solution.

Comment: I don't understand your update on CORS. You're doing a GET request, not POST. You shouldn't need to update the server code to allow this request..

Comment: You can directly decorate over controller like this : 
`[EnableCors(origins: "http://yoursite.com", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` if you are using .net MVC.

Comment: @PrateekGupta Server is Java.

Comment: @Potatosaurus are you using Spring?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Well the get request does not succeed unless it has the additional header, I don't understand it either.

Comment: @PrateekGupta I am not unless I'm mistaken.

Comment: Have a look at the following link for enabling cors in jersey :
[link][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25860490/enable-cors-post-request-from-angularjs-to-jersey]